# Derivation of angular momentum commutator relations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, operators, commutator

I'm trying to understand the derivation of the angular momentum commutator relations. How is

$$[zp_y, zp_x] ~=~ 0?$$

How is

$$[yp_z, zp_x] ~=~ y[p_z, z]p_x?$$

Answer (score 3):

Remember that

$$[AB,C] = A[B,C] + [A,C]B$$

With this, the first identity follows directly from the canonical commutation relation

$$[x_i,p_j] = i \hbar \delta_{ij}$$

along with

$$[x_i,x_j] = [p_i,p_j] = 0$$

For the second, the same relations tell us that $y$ and $p_x$ commute with everything else in sight, and so can be treated as C-numbers.

Answer (score -3):

$[zp_y,zp_x] =  zp_yzp_x - zp_xzp_y$

A very trivial fact is that $p_y = \frac{d}{dy}$

$zp_yzp_x = (-ih)^2 \frac{d}{dx}z\psi'=(-ih)^2 \psi''z$

$zp_xzp_y = (-ih)^2 \psi''z$

so their commutator is 0

This is because $\frac{d}{dx}(z) and \frac{d}{dy}(z) = 0$

**Answer 2**

$[yp_z,zp_x] = yp_zzp_x - zp_xyp_z$

$ = yp_zzp_x - yp_xzp_z$

Because $p_x$ acts on y and z in the same way

$= [p_z,z]yp_x$